# Como passar duas tabelas para uma só e atualizar os códigos

Tags: mysql

Há tempos atrás criei duas tabelas, sob nomes diferentes, (por falta de experiência), hoje notei que elas tinham exatamente os mesmos campos. Então, decidi uni-las. Porém, preciso fazer isto sem perder os dados.

Que comando posso fazer levando em consideração que serão gerados novos códigos (já que a chave é `auto increment`) e preciso atualizar as outras tabelas com o novo código gerado?

Existe algo do tipo:

```
insert into x select * from y and z
```

E ainda atualizando com os códigos novos?

**Tabela Quadro**

```
cd_quadro         int
nm_medida         varchar(30)
cd_progresso      int
impresso          bool
entregue          bool
```

**Tabela Painel**

```
cd_painel         int
nm_medida         varchar(30)
cd_progresso      int
impresso          bool
entregue          bool
```

**Tabela Evento**

```
cd_evento         int
nm_evento         varchar(100)
cd_quadro         int
cd_painel         int
```

Comment: O evento pode ter um painel e um quadro ou apenas um dos 2?

Comment: Pode ter os dois, apenas um ou nenhum; porém agora que perguntou... acha mesmo necessário 2 tabelas iguais com nomes diferentes?

Comment: Não, apenas uma tabela com um campo tipo, por exemplo 1 para quadro e 2 para painel.

Comment: @Lizard, conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um campo temporario na tabela Quadro

```
ALTER TABLE Quadro ADD cd_painelInteger
```

**Inserir os registros**

```
INSERT INTO Quadro (nm_medida, cd_progresso, impresso, entregue, cd_painel)
SELECT nm_medida, cd_progresso, impresso, entregue, cd_painel FROM Painel
```

**Atualizar as Dependencias**

```
UPDATE Evento E set cd_quadro = 
    (SELECT 
         cd_quadro 
     FROM 
         Quadro Q 
     WHERE 
         Q.cd_painel = E.cd_painel)
WHERE
    E.cd_Quadro is Null and E.cdEvento IS NOT NULL;
```

Dropar as foreign keys e a tabela painel